# The function can not be called in sapui5. Shortcut is not executable

Tags: sapui5

I have a button called EXPORT and now I need to create a shortcut to export file to excel. The short cut is Ctrl+Alt+E. When I press the shortcut it have to call the function "onCommandExecution" which will check the ID condition and execute the function "onExportToExcel". I have been made debugging and I the ID was not called in the function. In other words the function onCommandExecution has not been called. The problem have to be either in view file or in manifest file but I see that both  are correct!
**The problem is when I press the combination I do not get all of ctrl+alt+e. I get one of them in debugging.**

Does someone have a solution  please?

Thank you

```
//Controller.js file
           onCommandExecution: function(oEvent) {
           var mSId = oEvent.getSource().getId();
       if (mSId === "CE_EXPORT") {
            
               this.onExportToExcel();
           }
       },
        onExportToExcel: function() {
            var mSId = oEvent.getSource().getId();
        var oSettings, oSheet, aProducts;
        var aCols = [];
        aCols = this.createColumnConfig();

        aProducts = this.byId("messageTable").getModel("oMessageModel").getProperty('/');
        var oDate = new Date();
        var regex = new RegExp(",", "g");
        var aDateArr = oDate.toISOString().split("T")[0].split("-");
        var sDate = aDateArr.join().replace(regex, "");
        var aTimeArr = oDate.toISOString().split("T")[1].split(":");
        var sSeconds = oDate.toISOString().split("T")[1].split(":")[2].split(".")[0];
        var sTime = aTimeArr[0] + aTimeArr[1] + sSeconds;
        
        oSettings = {
            workbook: {
                columns: aCols
            },
            dataSource: aProducts,
            fileName: "export_" + sDate + sTime
        };
        if (mSId === "CE_EXPORT") {
        oSheet = new Spreadsheet(oSettings);
        oSheet.build()
            .then(function() {
                MessageToast.show(this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("excelDownloadSuccessful"));
            })
            .finally(function() {
                oSheet.destroy();
            });
        }
    },





    <View.xml file>
<Page>
    <footer>
        <OverflowToolbar >
            <Button icon="sap-icon://excel-attachment" text="{i18n>exportToExcelBtn}" press="onExportToExcel" tooltip="{i18n>exportToExcelBtnTooltip}"/>
        </OverflowToolbar>
    </footer>
    <dependents>
    <core:CommandExecution id="CE_EXPORT" command="Export" enabled="true" execute="onCommandExecution" />
    </dependents>
</Page>






  <manifest.json file>
 "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "com.volkswagen.ifdb.cc.sa.view.Main",
        "type": "XML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.65.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.m": {},
            "sap.ui.comp": {},
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.ui.layout": {},
            "sap.ushell": {}
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "commands": {
        "Export":{
            "shortcut": "Ctrl+Alt+E"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: The problem whe I wanted to add the code from view file and manifest file , they be all together in one code space, not seperated. how can I solve this?

Comment: Do not use [tag:sap] as it's ambiguous; [tag:sapui5] is sufficient